# NSFetchedResultsController on main thread ignoring saves to Core Data from a different thread?

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperationqueue

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` on the main thread. Also from the main thread, I asynchronously send out a network request for JSON. When that JSON string returns, I start an `NSOperation` that inits a new (background) `NSManagedObjectContext`, parses the JSON string, creates/updates `NSManagedObject`'s, and saves them in the context. The background context has the same persistentStore as the main context. With this, I have 2 questions:

1. I thought that any saves to the persistent store from any context (on any thread) would notify the main `NSFetchedResultsController` that there are changes, but so far it doesn't pick up any changes. Is there something I should do to notify the main thread's `NSFetchedResultsController` that there were external `save`'s so that the `tableView` updates accordingly?
2. So, on the main thread, I subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and correctly see when all contexts (including those existing entirely on a separate thread) perform a `save` operation. The [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) say that the `notification.userInfo` should have a dictionary of 3 arrays, one array for each of the "updated, deleted, and inserted" model objects on the background thread. However, the `userInfo` is always `nil` for me. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Subscribing to the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` in AppDelegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

And the method for when contexts are saved in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    DLog(@"notification: %@", notification); //not nil
    DLog(@"notification user info: %@", notification.userInfo); // always nil... why??

    NSManagedObjectContext *theContext = notification.object;
    if(theContext != context) {
        DLog(@"---- SAVED ON ANOTHER CONTEXT");

        // should I notify NSFetchedResultsController that there were context saves on background threads?
        // how can I merge contexts if userInfo is nil?
    }
}
```

I'd also like to know the best practices in dealing with multiple threads (with separate NSManagedObjectContexts) and Core Data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You observe the wrong notification: the name of the notification you need to observe is `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` (not `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`).

Comment: great! userInfo is now filled with the correct dictionaries. what about notifying the `NSFetchedResultsController` about the changes - do you recommend I merge these changes to the main context or is there an easier way to update the `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: The controller relies on the main context, so the correct way (indeed the only way) to do this is to merge the changes into that context.

Comment: Yes, you should tell the main context to merge the changes using `-[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:]`. If the `NSFetchedResultController` has a delegate, it will automatically refresh it contents and notify the changes to its delegate. Otherwise, you can reload the contents by sending `performFetch:`.